# rebuild ruby app without restarting apache in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2

Is it possible to somehow recompile app (when changing code) while in production mode, without restarting apache? I am using passanger...
thank you
Dorijan

Comment: Google "passenger rails zero downtime deploys"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** EDIT **

In your app's root directory:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

This will restart the Rails app.

[From the docs:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

> config.cache_classes controls whether or not application classes and
>   modules should be reloaded on each request. Defaults to false in
>   development mode, and true in test and production modes. Can also be
>   enabled with threadsafe!.

Terrible idea in production though as it slows down EVERY request. Best to use something like Capistrano for deployment and have it restart the server for you.

Comment: thank you...but I was thinking something I can manually run...like apache2 restart...but without restarting apache :)